# Three.js adding texture gives complete object color of 1 pixel

Tags: three.js

I have this texture of 20x20pixels and and object from a collada 1.4.1 model.
So I want to give this object this new texture for testing

[image]

I do the following

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.load("/assets/images/texture2/TextureResource129.png", texture => {

    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      map: texture
    });
    node.material = material;
    material.needsUpdate = true;

 });
```

Now what happens is that the object is in 1 color

[image]

How can I change the texture so it is just as the texture?

Comment: Do you have correct uv coordinates on your model?

Comment: I don't know how to get them. When the model loads it generates a `shaderMaterial` (model comes from program that export dae files 1.4.1). That shaderMaterial already has a texture but I want to replace it programaticly. How can I get the uv map from the existing shaderMaterial?

Comment: Does the generated `ShaderMaterial` use custom shaders? If so, it might behave completely different than `MeshLambertMaterial`. What do you see when you do `console.log(node.material);`? You might be able to change the texture directly without creating a new material with `node.material.map = texture;`

Comment: @Marquizzo This is the console.log(node.material) -> https://pasteboard.co/Ii4bDfJ.png I have tried to update all .image references in the uniforms section but that didn't work. How do you think I can change it directly. It does have custom shaders I think `fragmentShader` and `vertexShader` contain a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new material that behaves differently than the one that comes in your Collada import, just change the texture of the existing material. Do this inside your texture loader callback:

`node.material.uniforms.MatDiff2.value = texture;`

That way you just change the texture input to the existing material.

Comment: I tried. But that doesn't change anything on the scene :(